# Create Hive External Table on S3 throws "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found" Exception

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I'm using beeline on my local machine to run below DDL, and throws the exception.

the DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE `report_landing_pages`( 
  `google_account_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `ga_view_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `path` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `users` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `page_views` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `event_value` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `report_date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer') 
PARTITIONED BY (`dt` date) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3a://bucket_name/table'
```

the exception is

`org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:862) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:867) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:255) ... 11 more Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:42070) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:42038) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:41964) at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1199) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1185) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2399) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:93) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:752) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:740) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createTable(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2330) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createTable(Unknown Source) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:852) ... 22 more`

And my local HDFS works fine with "hdfs dfs -mkdir s3a://bucket/table"

And the wierd thing is, if I created the table not on S3 first, and then manually update the location of the table to s3 in metastore later, the select statement like 
`select COUNT(*) from report_landing_pages group by google_account_id` 
works fine.

How to fix exception in DDL?

BTW, I'm running with Hive 2.3.2, Hadoop 2.7.5 under MacOS X EI Caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

After place the S3 jars, the metastore service should also be restarted, besides hiveserver2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating the same table in my environment and it worked.

Check your : `fs.s3a.access.key`

```
"fs.s3a.secret.key","fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
```

properties in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you place all the required jars s3 etc to the classpath? 
(org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem)- this is a Hadoop class, found in the Hadoop-aws jar. An exception reporting one of these classes is missing means that this jar is not in the class path.

Comment: Yes. Other wise the select statement won't be successfully executed.

Comment: I put haddop-aws-2.7.5.jar and aws-sdk-1.7.4.jar under hadoop/share/common/libs. What else place should the jars be put in ? Also tried "add jar", "HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH' also won't work.

Comment: Did you try adding jars to hive classpath permanently using the hive shell interface this way- add jar <jar path>. Jars path one by one

Comment: Yes. Through beeline. And "list jars" shows correctly

Comment: a. what is the AWS SDK verison you have used and Hadoop was built on? Did you use multiple versions of jars?
b. Are you able to “unjar” the jar using jar -xvf? Does the jar indeed contain the package and class "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
c. As per the Oracle documentation, ClassNotFoundException is thrown following the failure of a class loading call
d. check whether dependencies from accidentally being overwritten by loading a different version of a similar dependency

Comment: e. Did you had a chance to look into this-
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/739/hive-how-to-dynamically-set-hiveauxjarspath-enviro.html

Comment: thanks. but not work. The point is that select statement can be executed on S3 FS, but create table failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. After placing the jar, the hive metastore service needs to be restarted

To restart the hive metastore, below steps needs to be followed:

```
1. ps -ef | grep 'hive'
```

Use above command to identify the Process ID (PID) that hive is using. By default, the hive used 9083 port number, so for a running hive metastore service, you can also check the PID using `lsof -i:9083` command.

```
2. kill <process number>
```

This kills the existing hive metastore service.

```
3. hive --service metastore
```

This command starts the metastore service again.

OR
If you are using hive-server 2, use the following command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/hive-metastore start
$ sudo /etc/init.d/hive-metastore stop
```